# Splitting up the installation tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

It has always slightly bugged me that [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) contains questions both about installing Ubuntu, and about installing applications within Ubuntu.

It seems to me that it might be good to split it up?

Comment: Does the tag "installer" refer to Ubuntu installation as well?

Comment: @jgbelacqua - yes it would look like it to me

Comment: meh, this is the good one http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7820/169736

Answer (score 2):

We could split the tag into [installing-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installing-ubuntu) and [installing-applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installing-applications).

This could possibly be also extended to [installing-hardware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installing-hardware).

Answer (score 0):

We could split the tag into [ubuntu-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-installation) and [application-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/application-installation).

Answer (score 0):

We could split the tag into [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) and [software-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-installation).

Comment: This leaves an overlap that could be more confusing than necessary.

Answer (score -2):

We could leave things as they are - it's not harming anyone.

Comment: It does make it harder to fund questions using tags, as [tag:software-installation] and [tag:system-installation] - though it doesn't 'harm' anyone even if it does waste time.