# Should we split the installation tag into seperate tags for the installation of Ubuntu and the installation of software?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was thinking after my previous post and probing the general of the SE sites, we should split the [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) into:

- [install-software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/install-software): for general software installation instructions. If you are/want build from sources, or the problem is apt/dpkg then you should use the according tags. This will absorb all questions in [install-from-source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/install-from-source) and [compiling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/compiling) and only the questions that fit in [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation)
- [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation): For installations of Ubuntu. Remember that Ubiquity is the graphical installer of Ubuntu and questions about it should use also the [ubiquity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubiquity). This tag should be used for problems with the installation process itself and the use of the installer. Post/pre installations problems, ie. boot, dual-boot, partitioning schemes, have their own tags. The questions that fit from [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation), i.e. about installing Ubuntu itself.

What do you folks says?

Comment: But questions about installing Ubuntu in general will be left out...

Comment: @Seth but you install Ubuntu using Ubiquity!

Comment: But my question has nothing to do with the installer, just the process of installing it!

Comment: @Seth gimme an example...

Comment: I can't find one right now lol. We do have them.

Comment: [tag:ubiquity] is not a good tag name for generic Ubuntu installation question: a majority of askers won't know the name, and it doesn't cover the alternate CD (or does it?). I'm all for splitting though, like we're slowly doing on [unix.se], with [tag:system-installation] as the tag name.

Comment: @Gilles I modified.

Comment: @Seth updated following Gilles advice.

Comment: @Braiam That's better.

Comment: What tag will installing fonts, cursors, etc. go to? I'm assuming [tag:software-installation] but it may cause some confusion in that it's not exactly "software".

Comment: @minerz029 [tag:fonts] and [tag:cursors] should suffice, you don't need to do a *How do I [tag:install] [tag:cursors] in [tag:lubuntu] [tag:13.10]* ;)

Comment: @minerz029 now that I think better, you are installing "software" in a loosy way, so software-installation may apply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that this is a reasonably good idea *in theory*.

- Software installation → [software-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-installation)
- Ubuntu OS installation → [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation)
  (IMO better because new users wont know it's called Ubiquity)

  - Maybe [os-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/os-installation), [ubuntu-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-installation) (keep derivatives in mind) or any other ideas?

---

The question is, how will we retag all the [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) questions to one of the more specific tags?
Almost every one of the 11,000 questions will require manual effort to analyse and retag.

Comment: That's the plan. And the method is simple. Just retag the ones you have answered.

Comment: [software-installation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-installation) and [system-installation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-installation) are the names we use on [unix.se]. We also have [install](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/install) which we're [trying](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2532/please-blacklist-the-install-tag) to [get rid of](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486/what-to-do-about-install-tag).