# Why are certain questions grayed out on the main page?

Tags: support

Lately I've been noticing that certain questions are grayed out on the main page. I know that when an edit is in progress the <kbd>edit</kbd> button is grayed out on a question/answer, but I've never seen this before.

Is this what happens to ignored tag questions, as I notice that the questions that are grayed out all have the tag `installation` on them (isn't that one that is being phased out?)

Screenshot:
[image: grayed questions]

Thanks!

Comment: I hope you edited those two questions with a single version specific tag ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, grayed out is ignored tags:

[image]

[image]

I have ignored windows 7, and a question with it is grayed out.

Comment: Is the [tag:installation] tag being phased out? Because Braiam told me it was.

Comment: I don't know, maybe not with 9 synonyms and 11,000 something questions.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Braiam is certainly trying to, see here [Should we split the installation tag into seperate tags for the installation of Ubuntu and the installation of software?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7820)

Comment: Please, if you see and installation tag, correct them please :D